# Setting value of a rule

Tags: replacement, rule

How do I change the value of a rule? For example, If I have `a = x->3`, how do I reset the value of `x/.a` to 4, so that `x/.a` returns 4?

The context of this question is, I have a list of replacement rules, ex. `list = {"name1"->1, "name2"->2, "name3"->3}`. I am hoping to change values of these rules without having to know the orders of the list. Right now I am accessing values of rules using `"name1"/.list`, but I do not know a good way of changing the values

Comment: `a = x -> 4`? `a[[-1]] = 4`? Your question is clear enough as it is, but it would probably help (to get a better answer, rather than having the question closed) if you gave some context for this--what are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This embarrassingly simple approach also works.

```
list = {"name1" -> 1, "name2" -> 2, "name3" -> 3};
list /. Rule["name2", 2] -> Rule["name2", 4]
```

which produces `{"name1" -> 1, "name2" -> 4, "name3" -> 3}`

Answer (score 5):

Try also this:

```
 list = {"name1" -> 1, "name2" -> 2, "name3" -> 3};

list /. ("name1" -> x_) -> ("name1" -> a)

(* {"name1" -> a, "name2" -> 2, "name3" -> 3}  *)
```

Another way would be to use associations as it has been already mentioned by Nasser above. The Associations have a very simple way to change a value for a given key: `an[key]=val`, where `an` is an association yields the association, in which after the operations the `key` obtains a new value `val`.

This may be summarized in the function below. In this function the list of rules is transformed into the association, the value of the key is changed, and the association is transformed back into the list of rules.

Its arguments are: `name`is the name in your list whose value you need to replace, `value`is the new value for this name and `rule`is the list of rules where you need to replace a value:

```
 replInRule[name_String, rule_List, value_] := Module[{an},
  an = Association[rule];
  an[name] = value;
  Normal[an]
  ]
```

which acts as follows:

```
    replInRule["name1", list, a]

(* {"name1" -> a, "name2" -> 2, "name3" -> 3} *)
```

Have fun!

Answer (score 3):

> I have a list of replacement rules, ex. list = {"name1"->1,
>   "name2"->2, "name3"->3}. I am hoping to change values of these rules
>   without having to know the orders of the list.

Why not use [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html)?

```
myRules = <|"name1" -> 1, "name2" -> 2|>;
list = {"name1", "name2", "name3"};
list /. myRules
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now you can change a rule without knowing the order.

```
myRules["name1"] = 99;
list /. myRules
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
myRules
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can also always get a normal looking rules out of the Association using `Normal` if needed, like this:

```
 Normal[myRules]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I am trying to deploy the program to CDF 9, so `Association` is not avaiblible. But looks like `Association` provides an elegant way to achieve what I want, I'd definitely try it in the future

Comment: @Yituo Association is new in 10. CDF only supports 9. But if you wait few days, CDF 10 is supposed to be out. Please see [Roadmap for CDF](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/288532) look at the bottom, post by Andre Kuzniarek, 9 days ago. He said it will be out in 2 weeks. So only few more days and it should be out, lets hope.

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {"name1" -> 1, "name2" -> 2, "name3" -> 3};

rrF1 = # /. HoldPattern[#2 -> _] :> (#2 -> #3) &;
rrF1[list, "name2", 4]
(* {"name1" -> 1, "name2" -> 4, "name3" -> 3} *)
```

Or

```
rrF2 = ReplacePart[#, {1, -1} Position[#, #2][[1]] -> #3] &;
rrF2[list, "name1", 5]
(* {"name1" -> 5, "name2" -> 2, "name3" -> 3} *)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a version of *Mathematica* that predates [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html) but you want better performance in update operations than you will get from directly manipulating a list of `Rule` expressions consider using [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues.html).

Here is an example.  I build a large list of Rules and an equivalent series of definitions to `defs`:

```
SeedRandom[0]
rules = Rule @@@ RandomInteger[1*^7, {1*^6, 2}];
(defs[#] = #2) & @@@ rules;
```

The time to replace a single rule is considerable:

```
rules /. (5399164 -> _) -> (5399164 -> "new") // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> ```
> 0.860049
> ```

The time to update one of the DownValues of `defs` is minor:

```
(defs[5399164] = "new") // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> ```
> 0.  (* below floor of measurement *)
> ```

But perhaps you cannot use `defs` directly.  For example if you are operating upon a held expression `Map` will not evaluate in the desired way.  There is a "trick" you might use:

```
asRules[s_Symbol] :=
  x_ :> With[{v = s @ Unevaluated @ x]}, v /; Head[v] =!= s]
```

An example of its use.  First a new `defs` with rules as in your question:

```
ClearAll[defs]

(defs[#] = #2) & @@@
  {"name1" -> 1, "name2" -> 2, "name3" -> 3};

defs["name2"] = 4;
```

Now a replacement operation upon a held expression containing `Print`:

```
Hold["name1", 7 + 7 + "name2", Print["Fail!"]*"name3"] /. asRules[defs]
```

> ```
> Hold[1, 7 + 7 + 4, Print["Fail!"] 3]
> ```

Note that none of the expressions evaluated inappropriately yet the replacements were made.

This introduces significant overhead for a replacement operation so you must weight this against the speed of updating (replacing) rules.  If you have many rules and the [`LeafCount`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LeafCount.html) of the LHS of your replacement operations is low this method should serve you well.  If however you have few rules and the LHS of your replacements is large you would do better to use a plain list of Rules.